# d3 trigger mouseover on path underlying other path?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseover, svg-path

I have [this chart](https://fiddle.jshell.net/w110yxmk/8/).

As you can see i inserted two paths.

There is am mouseover listener on the circles.

Now the problem is, that one `path` is overlaying the other and the circles belonging to it, and the event is not triggered when hovering an underlying circle.

Here the circle I mean:

[image]

I draw the lines and circles like this:

```
//draw line
let valueline = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
  .y(function(d) { return ys[count](d.val); });

let chart = chartBody.append("g")
  .attr("class", `charts chart-${count}`)
  .append("path")
    .attr("class", `line-${count} line`)
    .attr("d", valueline(data.samples));

//get dots for circle values
let node = chartBody.selectAll("dot")
                .data(data.samples)
                .enter()
                .append("g");

//add circle
node.append("circle")
  .attr("class", `circle-${count}`)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.date); })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return ys[count](d.val); })
  .attr("r", 8)
  .on("mouseover", showHideDetails)
  .on("mouseout", showHideDetails);
```

Is there a way to trigger the event on the underlying circle or do i have to use something else than the `path` tag?

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to group the path and circles element separately.

```
let chartBody = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "chart-body")
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
  //.call(zoom)

let rect = chartBody.append('svg:rect')
  .attr('id', 'rect')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .attr('fill', 'white');

// create group for path
let chartPathContainer = chartBody.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart-path-container');

// create group for circles after path so all circles are not covered by path
let chartCircleContainer = chartBody.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'chart-circle-container');
```

Then when drawing the path and dots, use their respective group as the container, instead of appending them into `chartBody`.

```
  let chart = chartPathContainer.append("g")
    .attr("class", `charts chart-${count}`)
    .attr("data-axis", count)
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", `line-${count} line`)
    .attr("d", valueline(data.samples))
    .attr("data-axis", count)
    .attr("data-inactive", false);
  //.on("mouseover", showDetails)
  //.on("mouseout", hideDetails);

  //get dots for circle values
  let node = chartCircleContainer.selectAll("dot")
    .data(data.samples)
    .enter()
    .append("g");
```

Just make sure there's no circles/dots that overlap each other.